# Accessing RPi from any computer using ssh or local network without password

Tags: networking

I would like to run a Python script on my computer that starts another Python script on my RPi. For this I need to establish a connection between the computer and the RPi. However for my case, the connection have the following requirements:

1. Should work wirelessly
2. No internet connection available
3. Should work on any computer (users dont need to get ssh key, enter passwords, manually login to a local network and so on...)

Is it possible to make a connection that doesn't require the above?

To establish the connection I have tried two methods.

1. Running a Python server using a local network on my RPi that my computer connects to.
2. Using SSH.

**Problem**: The problem with these methods is that the user needs to manually login to the PI's network and thereby will loose their internet connection.

Hope you can help!

Comment: "Is it even possible to make a simple connection that doesnt require the above?" -> Yes, write a simple server that responds to whatever msg.

Comment: I should maybe mention that im not an experienced programmer, so writing a simple server sounds advanced in my ears.. :)

Comment: By "simple" I meant like, a simple form of something (as in "a simple room").  However, I'm sure this can be done in like a dozen or so lines of python (just not by me, because I'm not a python user).  So I wasn't being facetious -- it doesn't need to be anything *complicated*.

Comment: ...Although that would mean you likely still have to create something to work with it from "any computer", which is a bit of a complication.  Probably the best way would then be via *a simple web page*.

Comment: If you're on the same wifi, know the IP address, and can use basic ssh commands, you can setup a user on the 'server' with no password and use ssh to run a command on the pi. Alternatively, it is really quite easy to write a REST server in python -- and even easier in nodejs -- that will take a request from a web-browser and run code for you.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I could set up a server, but it still requires that both devices are on the same network or have access to internet right? 

Do you know how "you can setup a user on the 'server' with no password and use ssh to run a command on the pi"? You will have to perform the "sharing og shh keys" everytime a new user wants to connect to the pi right?